# Upload new version of python library

Tags: python, pypi

I recently made a python library (most recent version: v1.0.0). I have made a few changes to it and want to release the next version (that is v1.0.1). I tried searching google to find the command to do so but found nothing. So I decided to run the initial commands (The ones used to publish the library) which are:

`py -m build`

followed by:

`twine upload --repository-url dist/*`

and I got this error message:

`HTTPError: 400 Bad Request from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ This filename has already been used, use a different version. See https://pypi.org/help/#file-name-reuse for more information.`

Can someone help me by telling me **what commands I should use to release the next version** or **provide a source to refer to**?

**EDIT:** I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016336/how-to-upload-new-versions-of-project-to-pypi-with-twine) and tried the [Best Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52130985/14257886) but it doesn't work and still gives me this error message:

`HTTPError: 400 Bad Request from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ This filename has already been used, use a different version. See https://pypi.org/help/#file-name-reuse for more information.`

Comment: Did you change the version in the source code of your project?

Comment: @BradSolomon not really in the "source code" per se, but in the packaging tool's metada file, ie `setup.py`, `pyproject.toml` etc etc

Comment: @BradSolomon I did change the version to v1.0.1 in `setup.py` and my  GitHub repository

Comment: @DeepSpace yeah. I had changed the version in my `setup.py` file but it is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload new versions of project to PyPI with twine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016336/how-to-upload-new-versions-of-project-to-pypi-with-twine)

Comment: @SpaceBurger I was just seeing that answer and tried that command but it doesn't work and gives me this error message: `HTTPError: 400 Bad Request from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
This filename has already been used, use a different version. See https://pypi.org/help/#file-name-reuse for more information.` I have added the details of that question to my question (by EDITing my question) as well.

Comment: Did you build your project again after changing the version ? Check if the package version is not already online, try to make a clean build and use `--skip-existing`.

Comment: @SpaceBurger I got it thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so the way is to clear all the files like `build/`, `dist/` and `src/<LIBRARY-NAME>.egg-info` and then run the commands:

```
$ python setup.py bdist_wheel
$ py -m build
$ twine upload --skip-existing dist/*
```

Running the commands in this order shall solve the problem.